# Difference between `sleep` and `pause` library functions in unistd.h

Tags: c, signals, sleep

From man page of `pause`

> pause() causes the calling process (or thread) to sleep until a signal is delivered that either terminates the process or causes the invocation of a signal-catching function.

From man page of `sleep`

> sleep() makes the calling thread sleep until seconds seconds have elapsed or a signal arrives which is not ignored.

```
/* This will wait till the signal arrives and it should be handled */
pause();

/* is it same as the above one */
/* This will also sleep for infinite time untill the signal arrives and it should be handled */
while (1) {
    int ret = sleep(3);
    if (ret != 0)
        break;
}
```

Source code of [`sleep`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/posix/sleep.c.html) and [`pause`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/posix/pause.c.html), both has been implemented in different way.

What is the difference between their implementation?
From application point of view when to use `pause` and when to use `sleep`.

Comment: If you run the second code on your phone - don't forget to recharge every evening... ;-)

Comment: The second isn't the same, because if the pause() is terminated via a signal, your program continues. Whereas, your sleeping loop will enter the body of your loop again and goes to sleep again and again and... You could however check from the loop whether a sigal has occured and decide to break out of the loop.

Comment: thanks @hetepeperfan, I changed the code for second case.

Comment: `sleep` returns "Zero if the requested time has elapsed, or the number of seconds left to sleep, if the call was interrupted by a signal handler."

Comment: right, that's what I had already explained in my answer. sorry for the hurried comment ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both could be trivially implemented on a POSIX system by:

```
#include <poll.h>
int pause(){ return poll(0, 0, -1); }
int sleep(unsigned int s){ return poll(0, 0, s * 1000); }
```

In fact, the 2nd is cheating, as `sleep` should return the time still left to sleep if interrupted, but who really cares about that \;-.

But it's exactly that complication the reason why `sleep(3)` is implemented in a more round-about way in the glibc source. Otherwise, any blocking [non-restartable](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) system call will do, including but not limited to `nanosleep(2)`, `poll(2)`, `select(2)` or `sigsuspend(2)`. What to use is more a matter of compatibility.

Comment: I'll change the description, since `pause` and `sleep` are library functions.

Comment: one should know whether `sleep` was successful or interrupted.

Comment: All of `sleep`, `pause`, `poll`, etc will return -1 and set `errno` to `EINTR` when interrupted. That's what you should check.

Comment: understood, poll does set errno EINTR when interrupted.

Answer (score 3):

> **sleep() makes the calling thread sleep until seconds seconds have elapsed** *or* a signal arrives which is not ignored.

So `pause` completely blocks execution of the thread until a signal is received but with `sleep` there is a second possibility to unblock the thread namely the seconds specified to wait for. So with `pause` you have to wait for a signal to arrive but with sleep, you have the possibility to only wait a certain time, like in a network you will not wait infinitely for a package to arrive (timeout).

Comment: I agree on that front, But what I want to know more is when should one use `pause` and when `sleep`. Both looks similar to me but on both are implemented in different way.

Comment: @Shubham The reason for the different implementations is, that `pause` can be implemented pretty trivaly by defining the signal mask for the signals to wait for and then simply suspend execution until the signal is received `return __sigsuspend (&set);` with `sleep` you need to check regularly if the time exceeded OR if a signal is caught which leads to continuing. Use `sleep` when it is certain that a singla arrives and you need to wait for it by any cost. Use `sleep` when you can not wait infinitely for a signal bc it is not certain if it arrives.

Comment: @Shubham it really makes no difference. Notice that instead of waking up your process every 3 seconds, you could call sleep() with a very long delay, eg. by abusing the signed->unsigned conversion: `sleep(-1)`. All (non-restartable) blocking system calls basically work the same, the only way they differ is what other functionality they offer together with "waiting for a signal".